# How to change photo every time, when I uploaded new photo (without updating page)?

Tags: javascript, php, html

How to change photo every time in img-tag "photo", when I uploaded new photo (without updating page)? I need to use javascript. Help me please!

```
<img src="" width="400px" height="300px" name="photo">

<input type="file" name="image">

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['save'])){


        $image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
        $image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
        $image_size= getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);


        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"upload/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);            
        $image_location="upload/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];


        mysql_query("insert into employee (image_location)
            values ('$image_location) ") or die(mysql_error());

header('location: DataGrid.php');

    }

?>
```

Comment: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/10/16/50-excellent-ajax-tutorials/ - You need to learn and write some code, we're not going to write it for you; least I won't. When you have and are faced with a problem, only then can we help.

Comment: How are you uploading the image? where is the form ? is the upload page and upload action script the same ? You should search for "Separation of Concerns"

Comment: Btw, you're missing a quote `('$image_location)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Javascript you can change Image src attribute with below code:

```
    <img src="" width="400px" height="300px" id="image_id" name="photo">

    <input type="file" name="image">

    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['save'])){


            $image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
            $image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
            $image_size= getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);


            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"upload/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);            
            $image_location="upload/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];


            mysql_query("insert into employee (image_location)
                values ('$image_location') ") or die(mysql_error());


        }

    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
         document.getElementById("image_id").src="<?= $image_location; ?>";
    </script>
```

but may be better to use absolute image location.